# Java How do I compare the values in an ArrayList and that of an Hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

This is my code

I have a HashMap which is `<String, JLabel>`

I want to loop through the HashMap and set the labels that are not in the ArrayList to visible(false). I have tried many things nothing seems to work.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<String,JLabel> map = ...
ArrayList<JLabel> list = ...

for (JLabel label : map.values())
    if (!list.contains(label))
        label.setVisible(false);
```

Relevant methods:

- [Map.values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--)
- [Collection.contains(object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: for not automatically downvoating a first-time poor-format question - +1

Comment: @Elist what do you mean?!!!!

Comment: @KickButtowski - The guy asks his first SO question and gets 6 downvotes (how about letting the guy fix his mistake?). Does that look like a warm welcome to you? Boann just proved that there are better ways to deal with such question. You can even answer it without seeing the code!